# Error al instalar SDK de Gcloud

Tags: python-2.7, sdk, gcloud

hola tengo error al instalar gcloud sdk, lo primero que hice para que se instalara fue poner

C:\Program Files\Python27\CLOUDSDK_PYTHON

para que pueda solucionar la instalacion de python, ya que anteriormente mostraba el error  y se me sugiere en el mensaje que te da Google Cloud Platform dice que no pudo encontrar el ejecutable de Python.

Y para que lo ubique te recomienda definir una variable de entorno llamada CLOUDSDK_PYTHON con la ruta hacia el ejecutable.

el problema no acaba ahi, ahora cuando se instalo gcloud sdk, no se ejecuta el comando gclooud init